# Angular JS ngView and ngRoute not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am new in angularJS.

I am trying to make a small angular app with `ng-route` and `ng-view`. When user clicks on the login button the URL will be changed from `localhost:8000` to `localhost:8000/login`.

Now if user reload the page the view of the `/login` will be loaded on 
page load.

Here is the HTML file I have with `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.

```
<html ng-app="loginSignUpApp">
   <head>...</head>
   <body ng-controller="mainController">
       <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now if user start from `localhost:8000` and click on login button then everything is working fine. But after clicking the login button if user reload the page then the `loginController` is not getting triggered. The view is not rendering.

```
var app = angular.module('loginSignUpApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $window, serviceFunctions) { 
    $scope.gotoPath = function (url) {
        $location.path( url );
        if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
    }
})
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $window, serviceFunctions, $http) {
    // some work...
})
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        title : 'Login',
        templateUrl: 'signIn.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        title : 'Landing Page',
        redirectTo:'/', 
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        angular.element('title').html($route.current.title);
    });
}]);
```

I am using Django as backend and angular for view rendering.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: html5mode requires configuration on the server; are you through with that?

Comment: show your whole html file please

Comment: Hey @KabirRoy Sorry, I am not getting what you are saying can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi @ThomasP1988 I tried this by removing mainController also but the result was same as before.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @FelipeSkinner here is the jsfiddle link : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5e2s83aq/)
From there you can see the html. Thank you.

Comment: i asked your whole html file so I could se if you're importing both `angular.js` and `angular-route.js` on the <script> tag. make sure you've added them both (since your jsfiddle doesnt include them)

Comment: Hi @FelipeSkinner, here is the whole HTML file : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yw31zjv/)

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your server, because as you use html5mode, your server can not divide the back part and the front part. Here is an example for Apache https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/